# Is a primary/foreign key concept available in Java?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, hashmap

In my java program I query a database and get a resultset. The fields retrieved are as follows:

- server_id
- threat_level
- client_id
- num_of_attacks

where each record represents an attack from a certain IP. I do not need the IP but would like to know the total number of attacks on a specific server to plot along an x axis based on threat_level, and also the total number of attacks on ALL servers for a specific client to organize along a y axis in descending order.

After the query, I then store the fields of the resultset into a hashmap of objects with the key being server_id after checking the hashmap if that key already exists; if it does then the total number of attacks is updated. By doing this I am able to take repeating records of servers, keep it as one object, and just total the field called "num_of_attacks". Now my next step is the final step to organizing the data to allow me to graph it but I am unsure of the correct approach due to my inexperience. My database mind is telling me to create another type of list or collection with the fields client_id and total_num_attacks, where client_id is the key and total_num_attacks represents the sum of all attacks on all servers for that client, and this can somehow be linked to the hashmap of servers through the client_id. So client_id is the "primary key" in one set and a "foreign key" in another which will allow me to first organize the clients, and then plot their servers.

My question is, is this possible? I've looked into LinkedLists but I'm not sure if it could completely meet my needs. Is there another data structure better suited for my needs?

Comment: I think this is a database concept ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller yes I think so to, but is this possible to accomplish in Java?

Comment: @solleks in Java you have objects not tables, and you can have one object as a member of another object which is kind of similar to forigen key

Comment: i didn't read ur requirment, but in java Set is a collection which will store only unique values if u can use that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Simply use another HashMap

Comment: @IgorRodriguez is it possible to have a hashmap of clients, since there can only be one, and within that object have a hashmap of servers, since there can be multiple servers for one client and be able to retrieve and modify data each field?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you only need to map a list of servers to clients (I didn't understand it before), you can use a HashMap where the key is the client's ID and the value is a list containing server IDs. Something like: HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>

Comment: @IgorRodriguez since I want to store multiple values for the client object and multiple values for the server object, could I have something like HashMap<Integer, Client<ServerList>>?

Comment: The value in a HashMap can be any object, so yes. But if you are going to create "Server" object, your HashMap would look like: HashMap<Integer, List<Server>>, where "Integer" is the id of the client and "Server" is your custom object that contains the values for the real server.

Comment: @IgorRodriguez thanks, I think this may end up being my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think below links might help you.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqf/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giquf/index.html